# Regex for float range separated by hyphen (for year and month)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate a textbox field that will contain a range (separated by `-`). Following are the requirements:

1. Need to validate year & month ranges, and have values like `0.5 - 3.11` for denoting `5 months to 3 years and 11 months`
2. The decimal places can be max 2 and 11 is max value in decimal place while 0 is minimum.
3. Both parts separated by hyphen `-`, may or may not include 1 blank space (only before and after hyphen).
4. The left part must always be less than right part.
5. Should validate values like:

   - `1`
   - `2.3`
   - `2.3 - 4.6`
   - `2.3-4.6`
   - `2.4-2.1` is invalid
6. No negative required for the float values

I tried to generate some regex but the closest was:

```
(0|([1-9][0-9]{0,9}))(\.[0-9]{1,2})?(-)(0|([1-9][0-9]{0,9}))(\.[0-9]{1,2})?
```

but it can only validate values like `1.3-1.9` but does not compares the left and right part. And only a single digit value is also not validated.

Comment: 7. Why you need regex solution for this?

Comment: @anubhava, I need to validate a textfield which will be used to enter a time period, that will be in terms of years. Like the one we have on job portals.

Comment: You won't be able to implement point number 4 purely in a regex, because standard regex syntax doesn't contain any operators to perform comparisons.

Comment: @pobrelkey, its ok, we can omit `4` for the time being. I'll write a server-side comparison method for the same. But please help me with the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could do most of the validation with a regex, but checking that the first value is less than the second value would have to be done in code rather than a regex.

```
function isRangeStringValid(r) {
    if (!r.match(/(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(\d|1[01]) ?- ?(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(\d|1[01])/)) {
        return false;
    }
    var y1 = parseInt(RegExp.$1);
    var m1 = parseInt(RegExp.$2);    
    var y2 = parseInt(RegExp.$3);    
    var m2 = parseInt(RegExp.$4);
    return (y1<y2 || (y1==y2 && m1<m2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another variant function with regexp for solution

```
function israngev(r){
    var res = r.match(/^\d+$|^\d+\.(\d|1[01])$|^(\d+\.(\d|1[01])) ?- ?(\d+\.(\d|1[01]))$/);
    return res!=null && 
          (!(res[1]||res[2]||res[4]) || 
            (res[1]!=null            ||
            (res[4]-res[2]>0)))}
```